# Nodejs parsing csv into MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv

I'm newbie in Nodejs.

I'm trying to parse into csv file into MongoDB, using `require('csv').parse` module.

Sometime i got that error:

> /home/user/projects/base/nodejs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:97
>   process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
>                                         ^ MongoError: server localhost:27017 sockets closed   at Server.destroy
>   (/home/user/projects/base/nodejs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:705:47)
>   at Server.close
>   (/home/user/projects/base/nodejs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:345:17)
>   at Db.close
>   (/home/user/projects/base/nodejs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:316:19)
>   at /home/user/projects/base/nodejs/read_csv2.js:95:8   at
>   handleCallback
>   (/home/user/projects/base/nodejs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:95:12)
>   at
>   /home/user/projects/base/nodejs/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:564:5
>   at
>   /home/user/projects/base/nodejs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:806:13
>   at Callbacks.emit
>   (/home/user/projects/base/nodejs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:95:3)
>   at null.messageHandler
>   (/home/user/projects/base/nodejs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:246:23)
>   at Socket.
>   (/home/user/projects/base/nodejs/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:262:22)

and i dont have any clue why. 
Can anybody give me any advice ?

Thanks

Comment: Did you debugged your codes and do you know really in which line while execution your codes it throws error, may you share your related codes about this process?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Well, Gentelments, i started to do little bit of refactoring before posting code here, and i found an issue (that was wrong usage of insertedDataCount variable )

All i can you - you are awesome ! All of you !